# JS document.getElementById.value not working properly

Tags: javascript

**// This is not printing any value in the console (blank) -- code 1**

```js
const addMovieBtn = document.getElementById("add-movie-btn");
const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
addMovieBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(title);
});
```

```html
<label for="title">Favorite Movie</label>
<input type="text" id="title" />
<button id="add-movie-btn">Add Movie</button>
```

**//This is working fine -- code 2**

```js
const addMovieBtn = document.getElementById("add-movie-btn");
var title = document.getElementById("title");
addMovieBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(title.value);
});
```

```html
<label for="title">Favorite Movie</label>
<input type="text" id="title" />
<button id="add-movie-btn">Add Movie</button>
```

What am I missing here? The first code (code 1) was supposed to work as well right?

Please advise. Thank you.

Note : I'm using the latest version of VS Code Editor, Chrome and Windows 10

Comment: "*The first code (code 1) was supposed the work as well right?*" no, it's not. It takes the value of the input *before* there is a value in the input. And then it's always printing the empty value. The second code gets *the current value* of the input every time.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable response. I understood the difference between the two code snippets now.

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet you initialize `title` when the js is loading, at the point where the input is empty.

To achieve your goal you need to get the value when you click the button.

```js
const addMovieBtn = document.getElementById("add-movie-btn");
let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
addMovieBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  console.log(title);
});
```

```html
<label for="title">Favorite Movie</label>
<input type="text" id="title" />
<button id="add-movie-btn">Add Movie</button>
```

Your 2nd snippet is presenting something else. You save to `title` the **reference** to the input ***element***. This reference holds the `value` of the input, and this value is changing according to the current input, but since this `value` is not a *reference* but a *value* (a string), you can't save it to a variable and access it and expect it to update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first code is that the click event is registered after you retrieve the value of the input. So even if you click the button, the variable `title` which has a value of `""` (you retrieve the value of the input before there is a value in the input) is printed. In the second code, your variable `title` doesn't store the value of the input but rather stores the Element object. Hence everytime you click the button the second code gets the current value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code, the value that you've accessed from the input was empty, as the code runs when the DOM was loaded and at this time, the input box is still empty. It is when you tried to get the value for the input. Even if you enter something and you click the button, it can't be updated, as the value was already stored in the variable. It can't be updated as the value is *not reactive to changes*.

In the second piece of code, you stored a reference of the input element in the variable, not it's value, and then you *accessed the value when the button was clicked*. Therefore, the `value` was already populated with the contents of the input box(unless the user clicks the button without even entering any value, *obviously*)

Off topic, but this is when the concept of *reactive* data/state comes into play. If you've ever used React or Vue or Angular or any framework that supports it, you should have heard about this. It basically means that the value of the variable changes when the value of the input element changes(in this case)(this is not the exact thing that it means) Here is an excerpt from the Vue.js documentation:

> Every [Vue] component instance has a corresponding watcher instance, which records any properties “touched” during the component’s render as dependencies. Later on when a dependency’s setter is triggered, it notifies the watcher, which in turn causes the [Vue] component to re-render.

Comment: I'm still learning vanilla JS, haven't dived into any frameworks yet. Good to know this, Thanks.